# Lifting a Markov kernel to act on measures of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have two finite sets $X$ and $Y$, and a Markov kernel (i.e. a conditional probability distribution) $f$ between them. Then if I also have a probability distribution $q$ over $X$, then I can calculate $$p(y) = \sum_x q(x)f(y|x).\tag{1}$$

While $f$ is a function from the set $X$ to probability distributions over $Y$, we can see equation 1 as defining a function from *distributions* over $X$ to distributions over $Y$. To be somewhat more precise, given a set $A$, let's write ${meas}(A)$ for the set of probability measures over $A$, suitably defined. Then equation 1 lets us lift $f\colon X \to {meas}(Y)$ to a function on measures, $F\colon {meas}(X)\to {meas}(Y)$, given by
$$F\{q(x)\} = \sum_x q(x)f(y|x).\tag{2}$$

Now, ${meas}(X)$ can itself be made into a measurable space by equipping it with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This lets us talk about ${meas}({meas}(X))$, the set of probability measures over probability distributions on $X$. It seems like I should be able to "lift" $F$ a second time, to get a new function
$\mathscr{F}\colon {meas}({meas}(X))\to {meas}({meas}(Y))$, given by
$$
  \mathscr{F}(\rho) = \mathrm{???}.\tag{3}
$$
That is, given a probability measure $\rho$ over probability distributions on $X$, I should be able to "push it through" the original Markov kernel $f$ to get a corresponding measure over probability distributions on $Y$.

Note that if this second "lifting" was really the same procedure as the first one, the signature of $\mathscr{F}$ would be $\mathscr{F}\colon {meas}({meas}(X))\to {meas}(Y)$, but my intuition strongly says we should be able to get a result in ${meas}({meas}(Y))$ and not just ${meas}(Y)$. I explain this intuition graphically below.

However, it's not obvious to me how to write down the function $\mathscr{F}$. I assume it's fairly standard, but I haven't hit on the right search terms to use. So my questions are

1. How can I fill in the question marks in Equation 3?
2. In case it's not obvious from 1, if I have an equation for $\rho$, a measure over measures over $X$, how can I write down an equation for $\mathscr{F}(\rho)$?
3. For bonus points, can all this be done if $X$ and $Y$ are more general measurable spaces, rather than finite sets?

Here's what I want in pictures. Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{A,B,C\}.$ Then $meas(X)$ and $meas(Y)$ both look like triangles, with the corners corresponding to outcomes in $X$ and $Y$. The original Markov kernel maps each corner of $meas(X)$ to a point in $meas(Y)$:
[image]

Then if I'm given a probability measure over $meas(X)$ I should be able to map it to a probability measure over $meas(Y)$ like so:
[image]

I'm just asking how to write down an equation for the measure on the right, given an equation for the measure on the left.

Comment: I don't think there's a natural way to do what you want. You can "lift" $f$ a second time by defining 
$$\mathscr F(\rho)(x) = \int F(q)(x) \rho(dq).$$ But that defines a measure on $Y$, not meas($Y$).

Comment: I'm certain it's possible. I added a diagram to show what I mean.

Comment: You can certainly achieve what you want in the second diagram _if you have kernel from $measX$ to $meas(measY)$_. I don't see that your diagrams give any intuition for how this can be done with a kernel from $X$ to $measY$, nor do I know of a natural way to do this. But maybe I am just ignorant. Hopefully someone else will give you a more convincing answer.